# Custom block translations

Tags: blocks, 9, layout-builder

I have build custom sections and blocks to provide for the layout builder.
Here is an example of my block code:

```
    <?php

namespace Drupal\hs_blocks\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\media\Entity\Media;
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;

/**
 * Provides a 'Custom layout blocks' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "hs_box_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("HS Box Block"),
 *
 * )
 */
class hs_box_block extends BlockBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $file                   = '';
    $box_person_position    = '';
    $box_title              = '';
    $config                 = $this->getConfiguration();
    $box_content            = $config['box_content'] ?? '';
    $box_bg_image           = $config['box_bg_image'] ?? '';
    $box_theme              = $config['box_theme'] ?? '';
    $box_is_ref_content     = $config['box_is_ref_content'] ?? '';
    $box_node_ref           = $config['box_node_ref'] ?? '';
    $box_omit_content_title = $config['box_omit_content_title'] ?? '';

    if ($box_is_ref_content == TRUE) {
      // Fetch the selected content type nodes
      $box_node_ref = Node::load($box_node_ref);

      // Bail out if the associated node is not in the DB
      if (!is_object($box_node_ref)) {
        return [];
      }

      if ($box_node_ref) {
        // Dealing with translated content
        $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
        if ($language != 'en') {
          if ($box_node_ref->hasTranslation($language)) {
            $box_node_ref = $box_node_ref->getTranslation($language);
          }
        }
      }

      // Get the body summary.
      if (isset($box_node_ref->body->summary) && !empty($box_node_ref->body->summary)) {
        $box_content = $box_node_ref->body->summary;
      } elseif (isset($box_node_ref->body) && !empty($box_node_ref->body->getValue()[0]['value'])) {
        $box_content = $box_node_ref->body->getValue()[0]['value'];
      } elseif (isset($box_node_ref->field_biography)) {
        $box_content = $box_node_ref->field_biography->getValue()[0]['value'];
      }

      if ($box_omit_content_title == FALSE && $box_node_ref) {
        // Get content title
        $box_title = $box_node_ref->getTitle();
      }

      // Get person position in case the content is AWID people
      if (isset($box_node_ref->field_position)) {
        $box_person_position = $box_node_ref->field_position->getValue()[0]['value'];
      }
    }

    // Process fields for the static content here.

    // process the fid and return a path to the template
    $box_img_result = [];
    $box_get_bg_image = Media::load($box_bg_image);
    if (isset($box_get_bg_image->field_media_image->target_id)) {
      $fid                    = $box_get_bg_image->field_media_image->target_id;
      $file                   = File::load($fid);

      $box_img_result['alt']  = $box_get_bg_image->get('name')->getValue()[0]['value'];
    }

    if ($file) {
      $box_img_result['uri']  = file_create_url($file->getFileUri());
    }

    if (!empty($box_content['value'])) {
      $box_content = $box_content['value'];
    }

    return [
      '#theme'                    => 'hs_box_block',
      '#box_title'                => $box_title,
      '#box_person_position'      => $box_person_position,
      '#box_content'              => $box_content,
      '#box_bg_image'             => $box_img_result,
      '#box_theme'                => $box_theme,
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc} Implements the configuration form
   */
  public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form   = parent::blockForm($form, $form_state);

    // Retrieve existing configuration for this block.
    $config = $this->getConfiguration();

    // Add a form field to the existing block configuration form.
    $form['box_desc'] = [
      '#markup'  => '<p class="h4">HS Box Block</p>',
    ];

    $form['box_is_ref_content'] = [
      '#type'               => 'checkbox',
      '#title'              => t('Do you like to reference content?'),
      '#default_value'      => $config['box_is_ref_content'] ?? FALSE,
      '#description'        => t('Check this, in order to reference content instead of adding static.'),
    ];

    $form['box_omit_content_title'] = [
      '#type'               => 'checkbox',
      '#title'              => t('Omit content title?'),
      '#default_value'      => $config['box_omit_content_title'] ?? FALSE,
      '#description'        => t('Check this, in order to omit the content title.'),
    ];

    $form['box_node_ref'] = [
      '#type'           => 'entity_autocomplete',
      '#title'          => t('Referenced Node Content'),
      '#target_type'    => 'node',
      '#default_value'  => isset($config['box_node_ref']) ? Node::load($config['box_node_ref']) : '',
      '#states' => [
        'visible' => [
          //don't mistake :input for the type of field. You'll always use
          //:input here, no matter whether your source is a select, radio or checkbox element.
          ':input[name="settings[box_is_ref_content]"]' => [
            ['checked' => TRUE],
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ];

    $form['box_content'] = [
      '#type'           => 'text_format',
      '#format'         => 'full_html',
      '#title'          => t('Box Content'),
      '#default_value'  => $config['box_content']['value'] ?? '',
      '#states' => [
        'visible' => [
          //don't mistake :input for the type of field. You'll always use
          //:input here, no matter whether your source is a select, radio or checkbox element.
          ':input[name="settings[box_is_ref_content]"]' => [
            ['checked' => FALSE],
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ];

    $form['box_theme'] = [
      '#type'           => 'select',
      '#title'          => t('Box Theme'),
      '#default_value'  => $config['box_theme'] ?? '',
      '#options' => [
        '1' => $this->t('Default'),
        '2' => $this->t('Primary Combination'),
        '3' => $this->t('Secondary Combination'),
        '4' => $this->t('With Figure'),
        '5' => $this->t('With Image Bg'),
      ],
    ];

    $form['box_bg_image'] = [
      '#type'               => 'media_library',
      '#allowed_bundles'    => ['image'],
      '#title'              => t('Box Background image'),
      '#default_value'      => $config['box_bg_image'] ?? '',
      '#description'        => t('Upload or select an image.'),
      '#states' => [
        'visible' => [
          //don't mistake :input for the type of field. You'll always use
          //:input here, no matter whether your source is a select, radio or checkbox element.
          ':input[name="settings[box_theme]"]' => [
            ['value' => '4'],
            'or',
            ['value' => '5'],
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc} Implement the submit of the configuration form
   */
  public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Save our custom settings when the form is submitted.
    $this->setConfigurationValue('box_content', $form_state->getValue('box_content'));
    $this->setConfigurationValue('box_bg_image', $form_state->getValue('box_bg_image'));
    $this->setConfigurationValue('box_theme', $form_state->getValue('box_theme'));
    $this->setConfigurationValue('box_node_ref', $form_state->getValue('box_node_ref'));
    $this->setConfigurationValue('box_is_ref_content', $form_state->getValue('box_is_ref_content'));
    $this->setConfigurationValue('box_omit_content_title', $form_state->getValue('box_omit_content_title'));
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc} Implements validation of the configuration form
   */
  public function blockValidate($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $box_theme = $form_state->getValue('box_theme');
    if (!is_numeric($box_theme)) {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('box_theme', t('Needs to be a text'));
    }
  }
}
```

I need to figure out a way to provide a translation of this block when placed on the layout builder. Mainly the content that exists here: `$form['box_content']`

Ideally, I would like to have the dropdown menu on the side, that will suggest to translate block. Something like you have with Drupal's reusable blocks.

I've seen various proposals that don't work, to the point of being confused on what exact use case. So, can someone who encountered the same problem point me to the correct direction.

Comment: If this is configuration, you'd need configuration translation.

Comment: @Kevin This is not a configuration, it is a custom block definition. I also added a schema yml but it is not seem to make any difference.